# Can't get GPS after login

Tags: javascript, php, gps

the GPS code works fine as long as i take out the php code.
is there some kind of overlapping interference between php and javascript

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
}
?>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    function showPosition(position) {  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;}
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check out your settings for your website/localhost. I think the location is blocked by the your end.

[image]

Comment: thanks i did check and the site is on as hosting package,
chrome is blocking the location and greyed out in the settings
ie asks to allow, is there a way to unblock it in chrome

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps.